# How to use unzip command to extract subfolder contents into current directory:

Tags: zip

I have a zip file: `foo.zip`.

The zip file extracts to:

```
- foo/
  - hello.txt
  - world.txt
```

What command do I issue to extract the files `hello.txt` and `world.txt` to the current directory rather than to the subdirectory `foo`. I could use the `cp` command but I want to do this all in one go.

Answer (score 2):

```
unzip -j foo.zip
```

> -j = junk paths. The archive's directory structure is not recreated; all files are deposited in the extraction directory

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ unzip -j foo.zip
```

The `-j` option:

> -j     junk paths.  The archive's directory structure is not recreated; all files are deposited in the extraction directory (by
>   default, the current one).